# C# Input string was not in a correct format. using c# .net

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Hi I'm getting "Input string was not in a correct format. using c# .net",

I tried to fix for now 2 hours and searched for answers in google but couldn't find. May you please help?

**[Link WebAPI](https://www.crowdwithus.london/api/endpoint/38FF9517A0E955C14A84336919F507DA1785E77E2EA79335A3930E59E3F3B7CD/deals/7)**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var myString = "\u003Cp align=\u0022justify\u0022\u003ESet in a period detailswith a\r\nmaster ensuite shower roomWC along with a modern open plan kitchen to hallway and open arch to living\r\nroom with further toyota.";

    char f = ' ';

    convert_from_unicode(myString, f);

    Console.Read()
}


 static string convert_from_unicode(string str, char c)
 {
     string rtstr = "";
     for (int i = 2; i < str.Length; i += 6)
     {
          string str1 = str.Substring(i, 4);
          c = (char)Int32.Parse(str1.ToString(), 
          System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
          rtstr += c;
     }
     return rtstr;
}
```

Comment: I recommend debugging your code. It doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: Have you tried debugging your loop? It should be pretty obvious why it is failing.

Comment: I've replaced the `Parse` with a print: [see here](https://rextester.com/KPM60864). Even if the `\u` were escaped (written as `\\u`), there is just one position in the string that is valid hexadecimal.

Comment: This makes it fail with a different problem. There are several problems with your code, debug your code to handle the first problem, the one you've posted in your question here. Once that is fixed, you might need to fix the length/end of string problem, but take one problem at a time.

Comment: It is not my code, I found it [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/714169/Conversion-from-Unicode-to-Original-format-csharp) (at the bottom of the page).  I changed 32 I added to the 16 that was there and worked.

Comment: @Sophia .NET strings *are* Unicode. They need no conversion. That string contains some escape sequences that represent *single* characters and could be typed directly. That `\u0022` for example, is just `"`. The contents of `mystring` are actually `<p align="justify">Set in a period detailswith a...`. Just try `Console.Write(myString)` or `File.WriteAllText(somePath,myString)`

Comment: @Sophia btw this very page proves there's no need to use escape sequences or conversion - StackOverflow is an ASP.NET web application. I was able to just type `<p align="justify">` without escape sequences

Comment: @Sophia as for the code's source, did you notice it's ranked  1/5? That's because it's useless just like *every* answer in that page - nobody realized that all calls did exactly *nothing* to the string because it wasn't encoded. The actual question was *not* how to convert the string to any kind of original form - it was already OK. The desired output was actually a *modified* string. The *original* string is just `سطور عبر الأيام 1`.

Comment: the problem is when you want to display it in a view page, it displays with HTML tag such as **<p align="justify">  <br />** . That it the thing I want to take out.

Comment: @Sophia that's a *completely* different question that has nothing to do with Unicode. It's not easy either - HTML parsing isn't trivial. If you know the size of the HTML elements you could use eg: `myString.Substring(19)` to get just the remainder. If you know what the end element looks like you could search for it and remove everything up to it. Otherwise you'd need a regex or an HTML parser to find stuff that *looks* like an HTML tag and remove it. A regex like `<.+?>` would have trouble handling eg `Consumption <= 10g/100Km, Speed > 190 Km/h`.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to delete `convert_from_unicode`. .NET strings *are* Unicode. That string *literal* contains escape sequences that aren't even necessary. What it *actually* contains is :

```
<p align="justify">Set in a period detailswith a
master ensuite shower roomWC along with a modern open plan kitchen to hallway and open arch to living
room with further toyota.
```

I got that with a simple `Console.Write(myString);`

The following three strings are identical :

```
var myString="\u003Cp align=\u0022justify\u0022\u003ESet in a period detailswith a\r\nmaster ensuite shower roomWC along with a modern open plan kitchen to hallway and open arch to living\r\nroom with further toyota.";
var myString1="<p align=\"justify\">Set in a period detailswith a\r\nmaster ensuite shower roomWC along with a modern open plan kitchen to hallway and open arch to living\r\nroom with further toyota.";
var myString2=@"<p align=""justify"">Set in a period detailswith a
master ensuite shower roomWC along with a modern open plan kitchen to hallway and open arch to living
room with further toyota.";

Debug.Assert(myString==myString1);
Debug.Assert(myString==myString2);
```

The fist two literals escape newlines and double quotes (`\n` and `\"`). The first one though uses Unicode espace sequences for `<`, `>` and `"` needlessly.

The third literal is a [verbatim string literal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/verbatim) which interprets escape sequences literally - `\n` is treated as two characters, `\` and `n`. Only `""` is treated as a single double quote.

**Stripping HTML from a string**

It looks like the *actual* question is how to strip HTML tags from the string. HTML parsing isn't easy. In most cases it's *not* possible to just use a regular expression like `<.*?>` to catch and remove tags. That pattern would match `<p ....>` *and * `Consumption <= 10g/100KM, Speed > 200 KM/h`.

A library like [HtmlAgilityPack](https://html-agility-pack.net/) can be used to parse the string as HTML and extract just the text, effectively stripping all HTML tags :

```
var doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(myString);
var plainText=doc.DocumentNode.InnerText;
```

This produces :

```
Set in a period detailswith a
master ensuite shower roomWC along with a modern open plan kitchen to hallway and open arch to living
room with further toyota.
```

Comment: I know that; my problem is when you want to display it in a view page, it displays with HTML tag such as **<p align="justify">  <br />** . That is the thing I want to take out.

Comment: **\u003Cp align=\u0022justify\u0022\u003** is only found in Json Webapi (when retrieving data thru API),  but when I convert it to C# object, there it shows HTML Tag **<p align="justify"> <br />**

Comment: @Sophia that's not what you asked though - you didn't ask how to remove the HTML tags. Those escape sequences are perfectly fine and *don't* need any kind of conversion or decoding. Web API won't emit unicode escape sequences either. Something else produced that string. Web API uses JSON.NET which would only escape the double quotes, ie `<p align=\"justify\">` in the *output*. It would parse the input without any problem. Just try `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new {x=myString})`

Comment: **I'm going to give you credit for this resolution after we're done.** I know it's a different question but you know, before I rush in to stackoverflow to post something, I first analyze that myself and come up with a question to ask in MSDN Forum or stackoverflow.

Comment: I asked the first  question cause after I debug the program I found that the debugger shows UNICODE characters in JSON mapping line (before the conversion to C# object)... and shows HTML tags after JSON is converted to C# object... and I found this resolution [here ](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/714169/Conversion-from-Unicode-to-Original-format-csharp) which was for UNICODE not for HTML... that's why I asked question related to UNICODE, no for HTML tags as I tried to search for how to remove those HTML tag the whole day yesterday but couldn't find how to do it,

Comment: that's why today I wanted no to waste my time posting and searching for the same issue.

Comment: @Sophia if you insist on looking for Unicode issues you won't find any solution. There's nothing wrong with the string, it's not even encoded. You're asking how to strip HTML. Use a parser like [HtmlAgilityPack](https://html-agility-pack.net/) to parse the string and extract the text. I posted the 3 lines necessary to do that

Comment: @Sophia that question you linked to doesn't have any valid answer either - all just return the original string. There's no UTF8 vs Unicode format issue in the first place. The person who asked confused the escape sequences for UTF8, which is a *byte* encoding. UTF8 deals with the *bytes* that represent a single character, not the escape sequences used to represent that single character

Comment: @Sophia in fact, if one wants to convert a string to UTF8 *bytes*, the answer is easy `var bytes=Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(thatString);`

Comment: Is **HtmlAgilityPack** free to use? or it's costly.

Comment: I added in my first post the WebAPI link that I use. In this webapi data I'm more concerned about two sections (Description and  InvestStrategy).